# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on stringByAppendingPathComponent

Tags: objective-c

I want my application to copy the video you taken with it to a directory, inside the App Sandbox.

Here is what I've wrote so far.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    int r = arc4random() % 100;
    int s = arc4random() % 100;
    int e = arc4random() % 100;
    NSLog(@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e);
    NSString *tempFileName = (@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e);
    NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    NSString *documentsDirectory 
        = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                                 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:tempFilePath
                                            toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]
                                            error:&error];
```

But after I test my app on my iPhone, program gets stuck after pressing use after taking video.
xCode tells EXC_BAD_ACCESS on

```
NSString * storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tempFileName];
```

What can be wrong here?

And uh, I actually want to 'create' a new directory called videos inside the app sandbox and save in it.
I couldn't do that, so I am using documents directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exception trace shows that your trying to send the isFileURL: method to an NSString which is not a valid method on an NSString.  I don't see any isFileURL: in the code you posted, check your code to see where you might be doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the message

```
isFileURL
```

to a NSString somehow and it is not a recognized message for NSString.

Turn on malloc stack logging, guard malloc, and zombie enabled in the debugger, then run:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x1b18b0
```

Where 0x1b18b0 is the address of the thing being sent the unrecognized selector.  It should give you more info about where in your code the problem is.

Comment: This answers something that the OP has not even run into yet. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs before that would of been an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with this line

```
NSString * tempFileName = (@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e);
```

Instead of actually formatting a string you are using the [comma operator](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html) which will ultimately sets `tempFileName` to the random number stored in `e` which will be an invalid address. That line is equivalent to the following.

```
@"%i%i%i.MOV";
r;
s;
//Now here is where the pointer is set to an invalid address
//resulting in EXC_BAD_ACCESS
NSString * tempFileName = e;
```

To fix this all you have to do is actually format the string. And to fix another issue you need to actually make a URL for `tempFilePath` like you do for `storePath`.

```
NSString * tempFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i%i.MOV", r, s, e];

...

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath]
                                        toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]
                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, it worked but now it gives SIGABRT. :( '2011-09-16 17:56:49.288 Helloicious[151:707] 71887.MOV
2011-09-16 17:56:49.356 Helloicious[151:707] -[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1960
2011-09-16 17:56:49.358 Helloicious[151:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1960')
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb) ' SIGABRT on int retVal

Comment: And I don't have isFileURL anywhere in my app?

Comment: I added the fix for that. You needed to make an NSURL for tempFilePath as well.

Comment: Pff, I am bored. 2011-09-16 18:02:03.121 Helloicious[163:707] -'[NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3137f0
2011-09-16 18:02:03.123 Helloicious[163:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3137f0''

Comment: Unrecognized selector? Hmm lemme see

Comment: It looks like you called it without including `error:&error`. Make sure it looks like my example

Comment: WOW, thank you! Thank you so much! '2011-09-16 18:07:17.953 Helloicious[189:707] Old File path : /private/var/mobile/Applications/64CABC00-E65A-4C07-AC22-CF99F45F7E06/tmp/capture-T0x183610.tmp.vGk6lv/capturedvideo.MOV
2011-09-16 18:07:17.955 Helloicious[189:707] New File path : /var/mobile/Applications/64CABC00-E65A-4C07-AC22-CF99F45F7E06/Documents/159448.MOV' :)

Comment: That method returns a `BOOL` so you could put the copy operation in an if check, and if it fails then you can check the `error` object for the reason why it failed. `if(![NSFile... copy..]){ NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]); }` And if this helped ya I wouldnt mind an upvote and an accepted answer!